# How do you build a Python app which can be globally initialized from the terminal after installation?

Tags: python

For many common python applications it's typical that calling the package from the terminal will initialize the application, via something like `spyder` or `sphinx-quickstart`. How can I set up that kind of functionality in my own apps once they've been downloaded?

The closest I've been able to get is, say for some app called `application`, calling `python -m application` with the `__init__.py` file hosting the launch protocols (which works, but you get an error in the console once exiting the application saying '`No module named application.__main__`' - kinda funny since it ran fine). I'm just wondering what the better way to do this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setup.py` needs to have `console_scripts`. [This article](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) explains things well, but the tl;dr is that if you have e.g.

```
mypackage/__init__.py
mypackage/__main__.py
```

where `mypackage/__main__.py` looks like

```py
def main():
    print('Hi!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

you can already run this with `python -m mypackage`.

Then the `console_scripts` stanza would look like

```py
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['greet=mypackage.__main__:main'],
    }
    ...
)
```

`pip install` will then create the console script shim. (For development, you'd probably run `pip install -e .` in your working copy directory.)

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Not entirely sure why someone decided to down vote everything though... haters gonna hate I guess.